# update post request alamofire

Tags: ios, swift

I am uploading an image with parameters (Full name, username, email) to my server with the following code, using Alamofire:

```
func uploadImageData(imageView: UIImageView, fullNameToPass: String, userNameToPass: String, emailToPass: String){
    //parameters
    let parameters = [
        "full_name"  : fullNameToPass,
        "user_name"    : userNameToPass,
        "email"    : emailToPass
    ]

    let URL = "https://webiste/add_user.php"
    profileData.fetchFromDatabase()
    let filename = "\(profileData.getEmail()).jpg"

    Alamofire.upload(.POST, URL, multipartFormData: {
        multipartFormData in
        if  let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image!, 0.6) {
            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: imageData, name: "file", fileName: filename, mimeType: "image/jpg")
        }
        for (key, value) in parameters {
            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: value.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, name: key)
        }
        }, encodingCompletion: {
            encodingResult in

            switch encodingResult {
            case .Success(let upload, _, _):
            print("success")
            upload.responseJSON { response in
            print(response.request)  // original URL request
            print(response.response) // URL response
            print(response.data)     // server data
            print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

            if let JSON = response.result.value {
                print("JSON: \(JSON)")
            }
                }

        case .Failure(let encodingError):
                print("Failure:\(encodingError)")
            }
    })
}
```

This part works and it all gets saved.
Now I want the user to be able to edit and update the profile. I am using the following but it does not work, can you tell me why?:

```
func updateImageData(imageView: UIImageView, fullNameToPass: String, userNameToPass: String, emailToPass: String, userID: String){
    //parameters
    let parameters = [
        "full_name"  : fullNameToPass,
        "user_name"    : userNameToPass,
        "email"    : emailToPass,
        "userID" : userID
    ]

    let URL = "https://webiste/edit_user.php"
    profileData.fetchFromDatabase()
    let filename = "\(profileData.getEmail()).jpg"

    print("all\(fullNameToPass), \(userNameToPass), \(emailToPass), \(userID), filename: \(filename)")

    Alamofire.upload(.POST, URL, multipartFormData: {
        multipartFormData in
        if  let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image!, 0.6) {
            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: imageData, name: "file", fileName: filename, mimeType: "image/jpg")
        }
        for (key, value) in parameters {
            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: value.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, name: key)
        }
        }, encodingCompletion: {
            encodingResult in

            switch encodingResult {
            case .Success(let upload, _, _):
                print("success")
                upload.responseJSON { response in
                    print(response.request)  // original URL request
                    print(response.response) // URL response
                    print(response.data)     // server data
                    print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

                    if let JSON = response.result.value {
                        print("JSON: \(JSON)")
                    }
                }

            case .Failure(let encodingError):
                print("Failure:\(encodingError)")
            }
    })
}
```

Comment: Not nearly enough info to answer your question… please expand it with some more detail. For example: What does *"it does not work"* mean? How do you know? What error messages are presented? From where? Which code do you know is working? Which code are you unsure about?

Comment: no error, it does not update, no idea why.

Comment: Would like to know how to edit and update with Alamofire.

Comment: This is really a question about your web service, not Alamofire. There is no way to know the correct answer to this question without knowing what your web service is expecting in the request.

Comment: The response error is: FAILURE: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 \"Invalid value around character 0.\" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}"

Comment: I am new to Alamofire, maybe I should not use responseJSON.

Comment: I replaced responseJSON with responseString and now it works fine. Not really clear what responseJSON stands for.

Comment: You should read the documentation or possibly Google "JSON"

Comment: I know I can do that. Thanks I figured it out myself.